# simulatation of multiple locations inventory based on markov decision process in python and simpy

Tags: python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, simpy, inventory-management, markov-decision-process

I would like to implement the multiple location inventory based on markov decision process with python specially sympy but as I am not expert in python and inventory management I have some problems.

I want to implement based on formula of page 12, 13, 14 of this link: http://egon.cheme.cmu.edu/ewo/docs/SchaeferMDP.pdf

Would you please help me to implement these formula with simpy python?

Thanks